# Python - read excel data when format changes every time

Tags: python, excel

[image]

I get an excel from someone and I need to read the data every month. The format is not stable each time, and by saying "not stable" I mean:

1. Where the data starts changes: e.g. Section A may start on row 4, column D this time, but next time it may start at row 2, column E.
2. Under each section there are tags. The number of tags may change as well. But every time I only need the data in tag_2 and tag_3 (these two will always show up)

The only data that I need is from tag_2, tag_3, for each month (month1 - month8). And I want to find a way using Python first locate the section name, then find tag_2, tag_3 under that section, then get the data for month1 to month8 (number of months may change as well).

Please note that I do NOT want to locate the data that I need by specifying locations in excel since the locations change every time. How to I do this?

The end product should be a pandas dataframe that has monthly data for tag_2, tag_3, with a column that says which section the data come from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can directly read it as a comma separated text file. Based on what you need you can look at the tag2 ant tag3 for each line.

```
with open(filename, "r") as fs:
    for line in fs:
        cell_list = line.split(",")
        # This point you will have all elements on the line as a list
        # you can check for the size and implement your logic
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the (presumably manually pasted) block of information is unlikely to end up in the very bottom-right corner of the excel sheet, you could simply iterate over rows and columns (set maximum values for each to prevent long searching times) until you find a familiar value (such as "Section A") and go from there.

Unless I misunderstood you, the rest of the format should consistent between the months so you can simply assume that "month_1" is always one cell up and two to the right of that initial spot.

I have not personally worked with excel sheets in python, so I cannot state whether the following is possible in python, but it definitely works in ExcelVBA:

You could just as well use the Range.find() method to find the value "Section A" and continue with the same process as above, perhaps writing any results to a txt file and calling your python script from there if neccessary.

I hope this helps a little.